# Failed to compile Boilerplate Generated Based on GstPlugin

Tags: gstreamer, glib

I have followed the instruction available in [Gst Plugin Development Basics](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/boiler.html?gi-language=c) in constructing the boilerplate for my sample plugin which is HelloWorld in this case.

I have created the sample plugin by calling the make_element tool in the cloned repo

```
../tools/make_element HelloWorld
```

After that, I have modified the *meson.build* in gst-plugin directory to include the generated source files namely *gsthelloworld.h* and *gsthelloworld.c*

```
helloworld_sources = [
  'src/gsthelloworld.c'
  ]

gsthelloworld = library('gsthelloworld',
  helloworld_sources,
  c_args: plugin_c_args,
  dependencies : [gst_dep],
  install : true,
  install_dir : plugins_install_dir,
)
```

I encountered errors after doing `meson build && ninja -C build`:

```
gst-template/build/../gst-plugin/src/gsthelloworld.c:184: undefined reference to `GST_HELLOWORLD'

**there are multiple lines of the same errors happen at different part of the source file.
```

I cant seem to find the declaration of `GST_HELLOWORLD` in either generated source files.

Looking at the tutorial in [Gst Plugin Development Basics](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/plugin-development/basics/boiler.html?gi-language=c), I see there was a declaration of macro that follows the similar naming convention with mine being **HelloWorld** while the provided sample being **MyFilter**.

```
#define GST_MY_FILTER(obj) \
  (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj),GST_TYPE_MY_FILTER,GstMyFilter))
```

However, I see none of the macro in the generated source files. So, I guess it might have been written somewhere else as the template provided in form of gstplugin.c and gstplugin.h looks very similar to the generated source files and can be compiled successfully if I remove my sample plugin from the build file.

Thus, is there any step I miss that is relevant for the compilation?
Thanks.

EDITED:
I was doing this on a PC with Ubuntu 18.04(gstreamer 1.14.5)

Answer (score 2):

In

```
    #define GST_TYPE_HELLOWORLD (gst_my_filter_get_type())
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (GstHelloWorld, gst_hello_world,
    GST, PLUGIN_TEMPLATE, GstElement)
```

replace `PLUGIN_TEMPLATE` with `HELLOWORLD`

Answer (score 1):

I compared with a working plugin and this modification to `gsthelloworld.h` worked for me :

```
#define GST_TYPE_HELLOWORLD (gst_my_filter_get_type())
G_DECLARE_FINAL_TYPE (GstHelloWorld, gst_hello_world,
    GST, PLUGIN_TEMPLATE, GstElement)

// You need to add this one below in your gsthelloworld.h
#define GST_HELLOWORLD(obj) \
  (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj),GST_TYPE_HELLOWORLD,GstHelloWorld))
```

Answer (score 0):

The gstmyfilter.h which worked for me is:

```
#ifndef __GST_MYFILTER_H__
#define __GST_MYFILTER_H__
#include <gst/gst.h>
G_BEGIN_DECLS

/* #defines don't like whitespacey bits */
#define GST_TYPE_MYFILTER \
  (gst_my_filter_get_type())
#define GST_MYFILTER(obj) \
  (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_CAST((obj),GST_TYPE_MYFILTER,GstMyFilter))
#define GST_MYFILTER_CLASS(klass) \
  (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_CAST((klass),GST_TYPE_MYFILTER,GstMyFilterClass))
#define GST_IS_MYFILTER(obj) \
  (G_TYPE_CHECK_INSTANCE_TYPE((obj),GST_TYPE_MYFILTER))
#define GST_IS_MYFILTER_CLASS(klass) \
  (G_TYPE_CHECK_CLASS_TYPE((klass),GST_TYPE_MYFILTER))

typedef struct _GstMyFilter      GstMyFilter;
typedef struct _GstMyFilterClass GstMyFilterClass;

struct _GstMyFilter
{
  GstElement element;

  GstPad *sinkpad, *srcpad;

  gboolean silent;
};

struct _GstMyFilterClass 
{
  GstElementClass parent_class;
};

GType gst_my_filter_get_type (void);

G_END_DECLS

#endif /* __GST_MYFILTER_H__ */
```

Also these are build commands:

- meson --reconfigure build
- ninja -C build